# If variable range is > 3 than do action else do other action

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, range

Some background: Each month I build a pivot table that has approx 30 or so business units (along the y axis) - lets call them groups. Each group has a number of GL accounts that change month to month. For example, Group 14 might have 10 GL accounts one month than the next have only 3. For each group, we need the summation of the totals for the GL accounts (that start with PL203000 & PL211010) for each group. Before we had to total these GL accounts for each group by hand. This has been solved with the code I have displayed below.

The code works perfectly when each group has more than one GL account (See pic 1)[image]

The problem I am facing is when there is only one GL account, the code doesn't sum the correct amounts (see 2nd pic).

[image: Incorrect version]

When digging into my code, you can see that it is summing the incorrect sections since i have a Rows.Count.End(xlUp) establishing the range. If there is only one GL account, it skips to the next section thereby establishing an incorrect formula

Perhaps my code needs to be completely revamped in order to account for groups where there is only one GL account to sum? If so, what sort of if statement can i code where it ignores groups that have only one GL account?

If not, than is the solution to have VBA count the range and if it is less than 3, ignore group and move on to the next?

```
'this section spits out the values needed to sum
For i = nRowMax To 4 Step -1
If Left(Cells(i, 1), 8) = "PL211010" Or Left(Cells(i, 1), 8) = "PL203000" 
Then
        Cells(i, 4).Copy
        Cells(i, 5).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 4)).Select
        With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 65535
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
End If
Next i
Application.CutCopyMode = False


'this section uses the values the first section specified to write the sum formula
'i believe the macro uses this section of code to write the first formula and the next section of code writes the formulas for the rest of the groups
Dim firstRow As Variant
Dim finalRow As Variant
    finalRow = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    firstRow = Cells(finalRow, 5).End(xlUp).Row
    If IsNumeric(Cells(finalRow + 1, 5)) Then
        Cells(firstRow, 6).Formula = "=SUM(D" & firstRow & ":D" & finalRow  & ")"
End If

'this section goes through the whole sheet to sum each group
For y = firstRow To 5 Step -1
finalRow = Cells(y, 5).End(xlUp).Row
firstRow = Cells(finalRow, 5).End(xlUp).Row
If firstRow < 5 Then firstRow = 5
If IsNumeric(Cells(finalRow + 1, 5)) Then
    Cells(firstRow, 6).Formula = "=SUM(D" & firstRow & ":D" & finalRow &")"
End If
y = firstRow
'If firstRow = 5 Then Exit Sub
Next y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dataset is an accurate enough example, you can scan through your business units and pick out only what you need. I have some example code here that will build up your sum range by using the `Union` function and applying that to the `SUM` formula when the entire business unit has been scanned. Of course, this is only an example that fits the data shown. You'll have to expand it to fit situations that are not visible to me.

To simplify the logic, I've separated the code into a function that will start scanning rows for a business unit and will stop when it reaches the end of the business unit -- *the test I'm using for detecting the start of the next BU is a line that does not start with "PL". This may or may not be correct for all your data.*

Because this code is checking each line and accumulating the sum range using the `Union`, if you only have one cell, you'll still get a formula that says `=SUM($D$30)` but it works.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim dataArea As Range
    Set dataArea = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

    Do While Not IsEmpty(dataArea.Cells(1, 1))
        Set dataArea = AddSums(dataArea)
    Loop
End Sub

Private Function AddSums(ByRef businessUnitStart As Range) As Range
    '--- loops through cells following the 'Start' range given,
    '    and accumulates the range of accounts to summarize
    '    RETURNS the start of the next business unit range
    Dim accountRow As Range
    Dim account As String
    Set accountRow = businessUnitStart.Offset(1, 0)

    Dim sumArea As Range
    Do While Left$(accountRow.Cells(1, 1).Value2, 2) = "PL"
        account = accountRow.Cells(1, 1).Value2
        If (Left$(account, 8) = "PL211010") Or (Left$(account, 8) = "PL203000") Then
            '--- add this account to the sum formula
            If sumArea Is Nothing Then
                Set sumArea = accountRow.Cells(1, 4)
            Else
                Set sumArea = Union(sumArea, accountRow.Cells(1, 4))
            End If
        End If
        Set accountRow = accountRow.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

    If Not sumArea Is Nothing Then
        Dim accountSum As Range
        Set accountSum = businessUnitStart.Offset(1, 6)
        accountSum.Formula = "=SUM(" & sumArea.Address & ")"
    End If
    Set AddSums = accountRow
End Function
```